# Certificate and KeyStore Configuration When Securing JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, certificate, keystore

I've managed to properly configure my java application to securely connect to my mysql, but I wonder: **Is that is the proper way to configure the required certificate?**

I've created a custom truststore and a custom keystore:

1 Imported the server CA certificate into my custom truststore file

```
 keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file server-ca.pem  -keystore truststore
```

2 Bundled the client cert and client key together into a pkcs12 file, and imported it to my custom keystore file

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -out  client.p12 -name clientalias -CAfile server-ca.pem
 keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12  -alias clientalias
```

I've configured my jdbcUrl to use a secured connection:

```
mysql://[my_host]:3306/[my_db]?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true
```

I've set my application with the following JVM environment options:

```
JAVA_OPTS="
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path_to_my_custom_keystore 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mykeyStorePassword
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path_to_my_custom_truststore 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mytrustStorePasswordPassword"
```

But that way, I've actually altered the default keystore/truststore, which is normally located at: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

And by doing that, some of the client-side libraries had started throwing errors when looking for their ssl certificates in the truststore

So, 
I've exported the entire default ca-certs to my custom truststore file (apparently there is no need to import it to my keystore, just to my truststore):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -destkeystore /path_to_my_custom_truststore
```

Now, **everything seems to be working as expected**, by my main concern  is that **I'm now detached from the original default JVM cert store** (keystore/truststore) at `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`, and therefore vulnerable to a future change in this file.

And to be more precise, what will happen when the JVM gets updated and new certificate aliases gets added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to define your own truststore including the CA root certificates you accept instead of using the default set of trusted root CAs of the JVM.

This way you do not depend on the eventual updates of the JVM, that could add an undesired CA or remove a needed one. Modifiyng `cacerts` would also affect others applications using the same JVM.

It is not needed to add CA certificates to the keystore.

Comment: I've edited my question according to your answer, in the way that I'm now importing the ca certificates only to my truststore. 
Thanks a lot